# UIWebView controller troubles

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiwebview

guys. I have two view controllers with two uiwebviews.
Here is my code:
First controller:

```
#import "articleView.h"

@interface articleView (Private)
- (BOOL) string:(NSString *)string containsString:(NSString *) stringToFind;
@end
@implementation articleView
@synthesize item;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    center = loaderView.bounds;
    loadingArticleContent = 0;
    if ([item objectForKey:@"article"] == nil) {
        [LoadingView showLoadingViewAddedTo:loaderView];
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        loaderView.alpha = 0.7;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        NSString *link = [item objectForKey:@"link"];
        currentArticleLoader *loader = [[currentArticleLoader alloc] init];
        loader.link = link;
        loader.delegate = self;
        [loader load];
    } else {
        if (webView.loading == NO) {
            [self loadWebView:(NSString *)[item objectForKey:@"article"]];
        }
    }
    UIBarButtonItem *itemBar = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(showToolbar)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = itemBar;
    [itemBar release];
    self.title = (NSString *)[item objectForKey:@"title"];
    self.navigationController.toolbar.tintColor = self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor;
}
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    favorited = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"favorites"] mutableCopy];
    if (favorited.count == 0) {
        favorited = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:favorited forKey:@"favorites"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
    bought = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"com.unnamed.habr.full"];
    UIBarButtonItem *space = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *item1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(share)];
    UIBarButtonItem *item2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"28-star.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(addToFavorites)];
    UIBarButtonItem *item3 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"71-compass.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(openInSafari)];
    if (bought == NO) {
        item2.enabled = NO;
    }
    if ([favorited containsObject:item] == NO) {
        [self setToolbarItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:item1, space, item3, space, item2, nil]];
    } else {
        [self setToolbarItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:item1, space, item3, nil]];
    }
    [space release];
    [item1 release]; 
    [item2 release];
    [item3 release];
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    if ([self.navigationController isToolbarHidden] == NO) {
        [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    }
}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}
- (void) updated:(NSString *)string {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    loaderView.bounds = CGRectMake(-90, 110, 110, 110);
    loaderView.alpha = 0.5;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:item];
    [dict setValue:string forKey:@"article"];
    item = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:dict];
    [self loadWebView:string];
    [dict release];
}
- (void) loadWebView:(NSString *)body {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSString *title = [item objectForKey:@"title"];
    NSString *blog = [item objectForKey:@"blog"];
    NSString *bloglink = [item objectForKey:@"bloglink"];
    NSString *author = [item objectForKey:@"author"];

    NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<html><head></script><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"mobile.css\" type=\"text/css\" media=\"all\" charset=\"utf-8\"/><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\"></head><body><h3><a href=\"%@\">%@</a> → %@ </h3> </br> %@ </br> <div class=​\"m\">​Автор: %@</div></body></html>", bloglink, blog, title, body, author];
    loadingArticleContent = 1;
    [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseURL];
    [html release];
}

- (void)addToFavorites {
    [favorited addObject:item];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:favorited forKey:@"favorites"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    UIBarButtonItem *space = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *item1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"124-bullhorn.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(share)];
    UIBarButtonItem *item2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"71-compass.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(openInSafari)];
    [self setToolbarItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:item1, space, item2, nil]];
    [space release];
    [item1 release]; 
    [item2 release];
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        NSLog(@"Link: %@", [[request mainDocumentURL] absoluteString]);
        if (bought == YES && loadingArticleContent == 0) {
            if ([self string:[[request mainDocumentURL] absoluteString]  containsString:@"m.habrahabr.ru/blog/"] ||[self string:[[request URL] absoluteString]  containsString:@"m.habrahabr.ru/company/"]) {
                ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
                controller.url = [request mainDocumentURL];
                controller.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", (NSString *)[item objectForKey:@"blog"]];
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
                [controller release];
            } else {
                webViewController *controller = [[webViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"webViewController" bundle:nil];
                controller.url = [request URL];
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
                [controller release];
            }
        } else {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"iHabr" message:@"Просмотр ссылок возможен только в полной версии программы, как и многие другие функции. Произвести покупку можно на вкладке \"Избранное\"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Понятно :(" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
            [alert show];
        }
        return NO;
    } else if (loadingArticleContent == 1) {
        loadingArticleContent = 0;
        return YES;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL) string:(NSString *)string containsString:(NSString *) stringToFind {
    NSRange rng = [string rangeOfString:stringToFind];
    return rng.location != NSNotFound;
}
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    UIBarButtonItem *space = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *item1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"124-bullhorn.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(share)];
    UIBarButtonItem *item2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"28-star.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(addToFavorites)];
    UIBarButtonItem *item3 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"71-compass.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(openInSafari)];
    if (bought == NO) {
        item2.enabled = NO;
    }
    if ([favorited containsObject:item] == NO) {
        [self setToolbarItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:item1, space, item3, space, item2, nil]];
    } else {
        [self setToolbarItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:item1, space, item3, nil]];
    }
    [space release];
    [item1 release]; 
    [item2 release];
    [item3 release];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    loaderView.alpha = 0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
- (void) webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"iHabr" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Не удалось загрузить статью. %@", error] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Понятно :(" otherButtonTitles: nil] autorelease];
    [alert show];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    loaderView.hidden = YES;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

@end
```

Second controller:

```
#import "webViewController.h"

@implementation webViewController
@synthesize url;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
    UIBarButtonItem *itemBar;
    itemBar = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(showToolbar)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = itemBar;
    [itemBar release];
    UIBarButtonItem *space = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    [self setToolbarItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:space, item1, space, item2,item3, space, item4, space, nil]];
    [space release];
    [LoadingView showLoadingViewAddedTo:loadingView];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    loadingView.alpha = 0.7;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
- (void) webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    item1.enabled = NO;
    item2.enabled = NO;
    item3.enabled = NO;
    item4.enabled = NO;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    loadingView.alpha = 0.7;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    if (webView.canGoBack) {
        item1.enabled = YES;
    }
    if (webView.canGoForward) {
        item4.enabled = YES;
    }
    item2.enabled = YES;
    item3.enabled = YES;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    loadingView.alpha = 0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
- (void) webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"iHabr" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Не удалось загрузить страницу. %@", [error userInfo]] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Понятно :(" otherButtonTitles: nil] autorelease];
    [alert show];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    loadingView.alpha = 0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}


- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    if ([self.navigationController isToolbarHidden] == NO) {
        [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    }
}
```

After opening URL in second controller, and going back to first, some scrolling up and down - my app showing error EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I turned on NSZombieEnable and now I see this:
*** -[webViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xec624b0
in my console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be sure to set the `delegate` property of the web view to `nil` before it goes away. Do this both in your `dealloc` and `viewDidUnload` methods, since `viewDidUnload` is not always called before `dealloc`. What’s happening is that after your view controller is deallocated, the web view still has a reference to its address, and is trying to send it a message (`-respondsToSelector:`).